# Is there a way to read the content of the sns message in reactjs web application?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-sns

We have a reactjs based frontend application and we want our reactjs application to read dynamic data published from aws sns message (after every interval of 30 mins) and show it on the frontend.

Thoughts:

1. Fan out the sns message to http/https endpoint
2. Subscribe reactjs application to that aws sns topic
3. read data as it gets published on to that https endpoint

Question:

1. Will axios be the best library to read messages from https/http location?
2. Any other thoughts/suggestions on how to code it?